# Writing a string modifying method

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

I'm trying to abbreviate a long list of .replace() sterilisation I'm applying to a string variable by writing my own jquery method.

```
jQuery.fn.ACsterilise = function() {
    var text = this.text;
    var sterilisedText = "foo test bar";
    sterilisedText = text.toUpperCase().replace(/\'/g,"").replace(/\,/g,"").replace(/\-/g," ");
return sterilisedText;
};
```

and then calling it

```
var stringToSterilise = "testi'ng fo'o st'ring bar"
var sterilisedString = stringToSterilise.ACsterilise();
```

But with no luck. I feel jquery is a bad choice as I'm working with a string not the DOM. Am new to javascript.

Comment: http://www.regextester.com/jssyntax.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is not made for working on strings, but on the DOM. What do you want?

jQuery instances:

```
jQuery.fn.ACsterilise = function() {
    var text = this.text(); // get text content
    var sterilisedText = text.toUpperCase().replace(/'|,/g,"").replace(/-/g," ");
    return sterilisedText;
};
console.log($("<a>Some odd-lookin' html</a>").ACsterilise());
```

[Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String):

```
String.prototype.ACsterilise = function() {
    var text = this; // current string object
    var sterilisedText = text.toUpperCase().replace(/'|,/g,"").replace(/-/g," ");
    return sterilisedText;
};
console.log("testi'ng fo'o st'ring bar".ACsterilise());
```